# check if date is lower than date

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, date

Im using jQuery UI datepicker, and jquery validate to my form...

I wanna check if the date you've selected is lower that: 01-04-1947, if the date you've chosen is lower then, then it should display a error message! 
Cant figure out how to do that- this is what i'øve got so far?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-da.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           //Hide div w/class
           $(".datecontainer").css("display","none");
           // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/class bool
           $(".bool").click(function(){
                // If checked
                if ($("#notificationbox_yes").is(":checked"))
                {
                    //show the hidden div
                    $(".datecontainer").show("fast");
                }
                else
                {
                    //otherwise, hide it
                    $(".datecontainer").hide("fast");
                }
            });


            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker(
                    {
                        defaultDate: new Date(35,5,24),
                        minDate: new Date(47, 3,1),
                        /*maxDate: new Date(49,12,31),*/
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
                        dayNamesShort: ['Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør', 'Søn'],
                        yearRange: '1901:2012',
                        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                    }
                );
                //Parse dato til format
                var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', "01-04-1947");
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', $('#datepicker').val());
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', $('#datepicker').val());
                if (date <= enddate) {
                   alert('error');
                }
            });


            $("#mainForm").validate();

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just set that date as the earliest selectable date for the datepicker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a `mindate` validation method that looks like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('mindate',function(v,el,minDate){
    if (this.optional(el)){
        return true;
    }
    var curDate = $(el).datepicker('getDate');
    return minDate <= curDate;
}, 'Please specify a recent date');
```

Then, in your validation rules, specify that your datepicker input should use it:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        datepicker: {
            mindate: new Date(47,3,1),
            required: true
        }
        //the rest of your rules
    }
    //rest of validate options
});
```

That's it.  See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/uFdu7/

You will probably want to define a better message in your validate options.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment by Anthony, why not specify the lowest possible date as the lowest possible selectable date by means of the `minDate` item?

```
minDate: new Date(1947, 4, 1)
```

Failing that, you could always new up a `Date` instance with the selected value and utilise its methods to determine the validity of the input (such as `getFullYear() >= 1947`, and so on). [Here's a reference](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/) to aid in doing just that.

Comment: Sure, but the user can still edit the text field if clicking, so the user can alter date the manuelly